# What is the best practices to store database connection related information?

Tags: java, database, configuration, connection

I want to know what is the best practices to store database connection related information?
What i know is ResourceBundle which uses a properties file is used for localization and is not suitable for storing database connection related information.
What could be the other best way to store this information in java?

Comment: What are the frameworks you are using? Is this an web application? If yes, then you can use the application servers connection mechanism to handle the database connections. In any case using XML is the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It is just a class library and i am writing Junits on that library.

Comment: Take a look at Spring Dependency Injection in that case.

Answer (score 3):

1. Property Files.
2. web.xml (Relevant read - [Context XML File](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html))
3. System class's jdbc.drivers property
4. Specify it on the server settings with JNDI (Application server/Web container, Tomcat Connection pooling relevant read - [JNDI DBCP Connection Pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html))

Answer (score 0):

you can also get those info from xml